# Are there good naming conventions to get around long variable names, without having to rely on comments for better readability?

Tags: python, coding-style, naming-conventions, readability

Basically I always try my best to avoid comments whenever possible. I watched many videos from Uncle Bob and regarding the things he wants to express, there are many things I agree to.

He once mentioned that ideally speaking, whenever we tend to use comments to give more information on why we do things the way we are doing inside a certain function, then that is the point where we maybe should reflect on the quality of the code we actually have written.

Of course I know that the background of certain things in bigger systems can be really hard to explain just by the code itself without having any comments inside. But still I feel like that maybe I just don't know enough yet and certain things can indeed be expressed with the actual code itself (given I use right naming conventions etc.)

Here is a concrete example:
I am working on a Telegram Bot which needs to retrieve data from messages inside channels and then forwards to other components of the rest of the system. Due to restrictions in that project I am limited to do this by only using the Selenium Webdriver. Currently I am really having trouble with chosing the right naming convention.

I found that at the moment, I can check if there are urnead messages for a specific Telegram Channel by its clickable WebElement object. It has a string member variable "text" which contains 3 lines, given there is no unread message available. If there however are unread messages available, the member variable "text" will have 4 lines. The additional line in this case contains the number of unread messages.

So the last thing I would like to do is writing a function like this:

```
    def isUnreadMessageAvailable(self):
        if len(self.__buttonElement.text.splitlines()) <= 3:
            return False

        return True
```

What I certainly don't like in the first place is that hard coded "3" there. I may need to use that exact threshold in several other places inside other python files. Also this "3" may change at any time, so when adapting to a new value for the threshold, I obviously don't want to edit it in 100 diferent places.

Instead I'd rather use something like this:

```
    def isUnreadMessageAvailable(self):
        if len(self.__buttonElement.text.splitlines()) <= Constants.AMOUNT_OF_LINES_IF_MESSAGES_READ:
            return False

        return True
```

As you can see, the name of the variable I replaced the "3" with, is really long. I mean it contains six words. Recently I feel that I am struggling more with having good names for variables, files, and functions rather than writing the logic to get my program to do what I want it to do.

I apologize for this long question, but I can't come with a way to provide readability to the code without using a variable which contains less words in that case.
Any opinion of your experiences are appreciated. Maybe some of your opinions/solutions can help me in the future when I face something similiar.

Comment: I'd argue this is less about choice of names (though `AMOUNT_OF_LINES_IF_UNREAD` is ridiculously long and verbose) and more about how to avoid long lines in general. `lines = self.__buttonElement.text.splitlines(); return len(lines) <= Constants.AMOUNT_OF_LINES_IF_UNREAD` is already a vast improvement, before you try to find a better name for the constant.

Comment: There's also the opportunity to take advantage of [implicit line joining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining): change `x <= y` to `( x <= y )`, and now you can put line breaks around `<=` as necessary to convert one long line into 2 or three shorter lines.

Comment: I would recommend reading [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) to get a feel for how to deal with long lines (and other stylistic issues).

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding PEP 8. 
In that case for me personally it was actually more about the naming rather than the line being too long. It was my bad that I did not express this good enough in the question. Sorry for that. Introducing that local lines variable to increase readability here is something I already came up with in my mind on my own. 
That easy reduction of 6 words to 5 however is something I've totaly overseen to be honest.

Comment: I think the first version of your function is fine if you explain what line four represents.

Comment: You already have a boolean expression so you can simply `return len(self.__buttonElement.text.splitlines()) >= 4`. I also think the prefix "is" in the function name is superfluous; the last word is an adjective which already tells the reader that it's a predicate (returns a boolean value).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is for three audiences:

1. the machine running it.
2. anybody else who has to work on it.
3. your future self. Once your code works, you are its most important audience.

Write your code so your future self can understand it.

The method you showed us has some assumptions baked into it. There's something special about your three lines, or two, or seven, or whatever in the future.

A method header comment is appropriate here, Uncle Bob nothwithstanding. It should explain what's special about three lines, and briefly say why or give a reference explaining why.

Long, explanatory, names are also helpful to your future self. One reason for that: they let you search all your code for references to them.

And, you can place a comment by the declaration of any named object to explain even further.

So use good declaration and method comments and meaningful symbols both.

Keep this in mind. It's twice as hard to debug your code as it is to write it. So if you employ all your cleverness writing it, you'll have a much harder time debugging it. Writing it for your future self helps cope with the difficulty of debugging.

Modern IDEs, editors, and runtimes don't penalize long names. IDEs show you declaration comments if you hover over names.  The two work together nicely.

Comment: Thank you so much for that input here. This is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping to find with this question. It is something I will be able to always consider during my thought process in the future. Certainly it will be of big help of course :D